# Problem validating app.json: Unable to perform cache refresh

Tags: react-native, expo

i had everything working fine, great tool Expo. however, after updating the expo (npm i -g expo --save) i started getting this problem.

i managed to solve the invalid version issue by adding "sdkVersion": "38.0.0" to my app config - but it was working fine before that. don't know why it started appearing now. struggling to solve "unknown o**ption `--assetExts'" issue here**, could you please help ?

Warning: Problem validating app.json: Unable to perform cache refresh
for \schema-undefined.json: Error: Request failed with status code 404.
Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 7.0.0, 8.0... 38.0.0
error: unknown option `--assetExts'
Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, what solved it for me was clearing the react-native packager cache.

I ran:  `expo start --clear`

**Expo cli docs:**
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/expo-cli/

In my package I added:

```
"start:clear": "expo start --clear",
```

just to help in the future...

Answer (score 4):

Problem got fixed for me after updating the expo-cli to the latest version:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```